# Enable update checkout on change for specific checkout fields in WooCommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm currently working on a custom shipping method plugin for WooCommerce. In order to calculate the cost of shipping I need access to the customer's phone number and/or email address.

At the moment I can see the checkout shipping methods are refreshed for specific checkout fields as postcode, city, state or country when changing or entering a value in the checkout page.

How can I trigger this same reload when the user enters their email or phone number?

Answer (score 6):

That is very simeple as you will see… It can be done just adding `'update_totals_on_change'` to billing email and phone fields wrapper class, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'trigger_update_checkout_on_change' );
function trigger_update_checkout_on_change( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'][] = 'update_totals_on_change';
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'][] = 'update_totals_on_change';

    return $fields;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

---

> But sometimes depending on your code, it will be not enough.